# mega menu not working well on my desktop view

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I want to achieve a multi-menu nav bar on the header of my website, but the second menu keeps going below the parent sub-menu. It seems to work fine on the mobile view though. can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?. below is my HTML code.

```html
<!-- bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!--Body -->
<li class=" nav-item dot-fix dropdown-holder">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Deposit Insurance Statistics</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-holder"><a href="#">Deposit Money Banks</a>
      <ul class="second-sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Micro-Finance Banks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Primary Mortgage Banks</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="service-v1.html">Micro-Finance Banks</a></li>
    <li><a href="service-v2.html">Primary Mortgage Banks</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Please extend the code to eb repoducable. A cut dwn part of the code that does nto show the issue is mroe or less useless.

Comment: Have you posted all of your menu code or just a snippet? I ask because there is some very standard Bootstrap 5 navbar code that doesn't seem to be present.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.